# Does a negative Dex mod affect AC and Initiative?

Tags: character-creation, dnd-next-playtest

I'm rolling up a Human Paladin for the opening session of the latest D&D Encounters season, *Legacy of the Crystal Shard*, and trying to decide where my dump stat (randomly rolled 8) is going. I know the Dex mod will negatively affect skill checks and saving throws related to Dex, but will it count against my initiative and AC as well?

Right now his stat array is:

STR 16
DEX 8
CON 11
INT 14
WIS 14
CHA 16

I plan on having him use Heavy armor, specifically chain-mail w/heavy shield.

Comment: I don't know how many levels you are taking, but swapping INT and CON would be nice for your HP; especially since you will probably be close to the front line, and might want a +2 to con saves.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Intiative will be affected, but AC will not.

- Initiative is DEX + d20. If your DEX is -1 then it's going to be d20-1.
- AC in your case ignores DEX because you're wearing heavy armor. You would take a penalty in either light or medium armor.

Reading the sections on both of these, they do not mention exceptions for negative DEX.